# SharePoint online storage full

Tags: azure, office365, azure-blob-storage, sharepoint-online

Our SharePoint online storage is full, it's expensive to buy extra storage on SharePoint online. I want to copy the folders from SharePoint Online to Azure Blob or Azure file shares cool access tier as a storage Archive. I tried using power automate and logic apps, it just creates the rules for newly created files but no option to move the already created Sharepoint online folders. Please advise me with any steps or recommendations.

Comment: Looks like the online storage limit is 1Tb. First recommendation I found was to emptying the recycle bin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the flow I followed to achieve your requirement.

First I tried to list the files inside the desired folder using `List folder` action of sharepoint which gives me an option to retireve File Identifier of a particular file.

[image]

In the next step I tried looping inside the folder mentioned in the previous step to retrieving the metadata of the file using `Get file metadata` action and get the content of the file using `Get file content` action of sharepoint.

[image]

In the next step I used `Create blob (V2)` action of Azure blob storage to create blobs inside the storage using the file content and the metadata of the files from sharepoint.

[image]

This step is not required but if you want tto automate deleting all the files from your sharepoint, you can use `Delete file` action of sharepoint to delete the file which you have copied to sharepoint.

[image]

Below is the whole flow of my logic app

[image]

**RESULTS:**

***Below are the files that are already presnt in my Sharepoint site:-***

[image]

***In my storage account***

[image]

***NOTE:*** If you are trying to automate deletion of files from sharepoint then make sure the files are moving from sharepoint to blob storage first (i.e., without using the delete file action) and then, after the transfer is completed try creating a new flow with delete blob action to delete the files.

To reproduce the same in your logic apps, you can use the below code-view.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Create_blob_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": "@body('Get_file_content')",
                            "headers": {
                                "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files",
                            "queries": {
                                "folderPath": "/container",
                                "name": "@body('Get_file_metadata')?['DisplayName']",
                                "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Get_file_content": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "runtimeConfiguration": {
                            "contentTransfer": {
                                "transferMode": "Chunked"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "Get_file_content": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<SITE_URL>'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['Id'])}/content",
                            "queries": {
                                "inferContentType": true
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Get_file_metadata": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "Get_file_metadata": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<SITE_URL>'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['Id'])}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('List_folder')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "List_folder": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "List_folder": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<SITE_URL>'))}/folders/@{encodeURIComponent('%252fShared%2bDocuments')}"
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "%252fShared%2bDocuments": "/Shared Documents"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "sharepointonline": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sharepointonline",
                    "connectionName": "sharepointonline",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/sharepointonline"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```